# How to select Text using Render2 ( Angular )

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I would like to create a directive that selects the entire text in an `<input>`

Before in older versions of Angular, I did the following :

```
import { OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer, Input, Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
 selector: '[appSelectText]',
})
export class SelectTextDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input('appSelectText') selectText: boolean;

    constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.selectText) {
            this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.hostElement.nativeElement, 'select');
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, It would appear that `Renderer` has been deprecated in favor of `Renderer2` which does not have the `invokeElementMethod`. Searching around, I've found solutions such as:

1.`this.renderer2.selectRootElement(this.hostElement.nativeElement).focus();`, which works for focus, but does not seem to work for `.select()`

2. `this.hostElement.nativeElement.select();`

---

**Solution**

Used @eliseo's help below. But I discovered that I had to wrap the `.select()` within a setTimeout, my best guess is that it was firing too soon. The following worked like a charm.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelectText]',
})
export class SelectTextDirective {
  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('focus', [])
  onFocus() {
    // SetTimeout (without time parameter) helps make sure this runs when it's supposed to 
setTimeout(() => {
      this.hostElement.nativeElement.select();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can use simply `this.hostElement.nativeElement.select()`

Comment: @Eliseo, Just tried it. No luck with ( Chrome, Firefox, or Safari) :/

Comment: I complementary my comment, I hope this help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alberto, if we make a simple directive like

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[selectText]',
})
export class SelectTextDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input('selectText') selectText: any;

    constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {
            this.hostElement.nativeElement.select();
    }
}
```

If we has a input

```
<input selectText value="hello word">
```

Our input becomes selected. But, this only has interest if we want at very first state of the aplication the input becomes selected or if we has the input inside a div with a *ngIf that becomes false to true,some like

```
<input *ngIf="value" selectText value="hello word" >
<button (click)="value=!value">click</button>
```

Its posible if we want, in focus, select the text. For this. We can use `@HostListener`

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[selectText]',
})
  export class SelectTextDirective {
  @HostListener('focus', [])
  onFocus() {
        this.hostElement.nativeElement.select();
  }

  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {}
}
```

Finally if we want use a Input, using a setter, not ngOnInit

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[selectText]',
})
export class SelectTextDirective {
  @Input()set selectText(value)
  {
      if (value)
        this.hostElement.nativeElement.select();
  }
  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {}
}
```

And has a input and a button like, see that we need put the value to false

```
<input [selectText]="value" value="hello word" (blur)="value=false">
<button (click)="value=true">click</button>
```